# Not able to index multiple timestamp for an object in thinking sphinx

Tags: ruby-on-rails, thinking-sphinx

I have two models user and orders.

I have one in User model as has_many orders.

I am creating one index in thinking sphinx like :

has association(:created_at), as: :order_time, type: :timestamp

Now I want to search for users who have created any order in some time range. and using above index as

User.search with: {:order_time => t1..t2}

But, this is not giving accurate results. Any idea what am I doing wrong here.

Also I tried writing a sql query also something like

user_order_time = <<-SQL
    SELECT  orders.created_at
    FROM    orders
    WHERE   (orders.creator_id = users.id)
SQL

and added index in this way

has "#{user_order_time}", as: :order_time, type: :timestamp

and tries to use this index, even this isn't working.

Can anyone tell me the problem with each approach.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, this answer is written presuming you're using SQL-backed indices (using the `:with => :active_record` option in your index definition) rather than real-time indices, and you're using Thinking Sphinx v3.

To cover your second approach first:

```
user_order_time = <<-SQL SELECT orders.created_at FROM orders WHERE (orders.creator_id = users.id) SQL
has "#{user_order_time}", as: :order_time, type: :timestamp
```

This will not work. You *can* refer to SQL snippets in attributes and fields, but only the sections that go in the SELECT clause. You **cannot** use full SQL queries.

However, with this approach, you're on the right track:

```
has association(:created_at), as: :order_time, type: :timestamp
```

Are you using `association` there just when writing this question, not in your actual code? Because it *should* be something like this:

```
has orders.created_at, as: :order_time
```

I've not specified the type - Thinking Sphinx will automatically detect this from the database.

If that doesn't work, it's worth looking at the generated SQL query in the Sphinx configuration file for clues as to why it's not returning the values you're expecting (locally, that's `config/development.sphinx.conf`, and you're looking for the sql_query setting in source `user_core_0`).